# Azure Function App and Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client Nuget Packages Conflicts in Dependency

Tags: azure-functions, nuget-package

Although my title mentions a specific case, perhaps this is an issue in general. I am trying to develop an Azure Function App which will use `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`.

Now, TeamFoundation Client needs `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.3)`, while Azure Function App SDK needs `Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1)`; Note the **> and >=**;

Clearly both the conditions cannot be satisfied. One option is to choose a downgraded version of TeamFoundationServer client so the requirements for NewtonSoft.Json is met. Not sure if this is the only feasible solution here. It looks odd for a package to require specific version rather than minimum version.

In any case, how can the dependency conflict on Newtonsoft.json for Azure Function App and Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client be resolved?

Comment: You probably are working with v1 function. Do you plan to move to v2 where Newtonsoft.Json = 11.0.2?